# syntax error при выполнении cursor.execute

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlite3, database-cursor

Код функции:

```
SEARCH_MOVIES = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title LIKE %?%;" 
search_term = input("Enter the partial movie title:") 

def search_movies(search_term):
    with connection:
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(SEARCH_MOVIES, (f"%{search_term}%",))
        return cursor.fetchall()
```

Лог ошибки:

```
File "D:\Programming\Python\Python+PostgreSQL_2.0\movie_watch_list\app.py", line 81, in <module>
    prompt_search_movies()
  File "D:\Programming\Python\Python+PostgreSQL_2.0\movie_watch_list\app.py", line 54, in prompt_search_movies
    movies = database.search_movies(search_term)
  File "D:\Programming\Python\Python+PostgreSQL_2.0\movie_watch_list\database.py", line 67, in search_movies
    cursor.execute(SEARCH_MOVIES, (f"%{search_term}%",))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error
```

Comment: попробуйте: `(f"{search_term}",)`

Comment: что в search_term?

Comment: В таких вопросах надо приводить __воспроизводимые__ примеры данных! Что у вас в переменных `SEARCH_MOVIES` и `search_term`?

Comment: Первый вариант не сработал.

SEARCH_MOVIES = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title LIKE %?%;"
search_term = input("Enter the partial movie title:")

Comment: Эникейщик, а про какое смешивание вы у меня имеете ввиду?

Comment: @Alexander_Sky не, я перепутал.

Comment: Окей, понял тебя

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас ошибка в SQL запросе. SQL движок ожидает такой запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title LIKE '%string%'
```

Обратите внимание на одиночные кавычки!
В том случае когда вы используете параметризованные запросы, драйвер БД сам добавит одиночные кавычки для строковых параметров. Т.е. при вызове:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title LIKE %?%;", ("%Star Wars%",))
```

SQL движок получит такой запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title LIKE %'%Star Wars%'%;
# NOTE: ------------------------------^     ------->^
```

**NOTE:** Символ процента **вне строкового литерала** (строка обрамленная одинарными кавычками) - является нарушением SQL синтаксиса.

---

Поэтому попробуйте так:

```
SEARCH_MOVIES = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title LIKE ?"
```

с таким SQL запросом ваш код должен работать правильно:

```
cursor.execute(SEARCH_MOVIES, (f"%{search_term}%",))
```